# dap-server-path is nil when attempting to debug Python file in emacs with dap-mode?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I'm trying to run `dap-python` to debug a Python file, but I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  dap--create-session((:type "python" :cwd "/home/yelnat/Documents/programmin/python-test/" :request "launch" :name "My App" :program "/home/yelnat/Documents/programmin/python-test/test..." :args [] :dap-server-path (nil "-m" "debugpy.adapter")))
  dap-start-debugging-noexpand((:type "python" :cwd "/home/yelnat/Documents/programmin/python-test/" :request "launch" :name "My App" :program "/home/yelnat/Documents/programmin/python-test/test..." :args [] :dap-server-path (nil "-m" "debugpy.adapter")))
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x785353ff795e90b>)()
  dap-debug((:type "python" :args "" :cwd "/home/yelnat/Documents/programmin/python-test/" :request "launch" :name "My App"))
  funcall-interactively(dap-debug (:type "python" :args "" :cwd "/home/yelnat/Documents/programmin/python-test/" :request "launch" :name "My App"))
  command-execute(dap-debug record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "dap-debug" "dap-deb")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "dap-debug" "dap-deb")
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

I've tried a few different config files and I searched the dap website for an answer but I can't find it saying anything about where the dap-server should be.

The only thing that I think could be causing the issue is that I use Debian 12 and installed a version of Python 3.10 to install any system wide packages that I might want (packages like `debugpy`). I set up an alias for Python3.10 and use `exec-path-from-shell`, but I'm not sure if that'll affect `dap-mode`, so it might be using my python version that doesn't have debugpy.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution, but it's rather quick and dirty. I've just set a link from /bin/python to /bin/python3 (by doing `sudo ln -s /bin/python3  /bin/python`), which allows dap to find the python interpreter. If anyone knows a way to pass the path of the python interpreter to dap, that would probably be the best solution.